# html5 button with image

Tags: html, button

I want to put some buttons onto the logo picture. I set first button and try to position it on the top right corner of the logo picture... Picture has width 100% and picture should be 100x100, but when do padding, the image is multiplying....

```
 <header>
    <button id="about" onclick="location.href='#';"> </button>
    <img id="logo" src="Content/images/logo.jpg" /> <br/>
</header>

#about {
position: absolute;
background-image: url('Content/images/about.png');
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add this property to `#about`,

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Padding will change the width of the button and won't affect image positioning, if you want to move the background image, try this,

```
background-position: x y;
```

Here `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the image.

Furthermore, you could re-factor and use the `background` short-hand for better readability,

```
background: url('Content/images/about.png') x y no-repeat;
```

Comment: Now the picture isn't repeating, but padding changes only the width of the button....

Comment: Edited my answer please have a look